# Can't get a grub prompt or menu on boot

Tags: grub, macbook

I'm running ElementaryOS Loki on a MacBook Pro which was previously running OS X 10.11.5. Now, I want to boot something (another Linux) alongside Elementary, but I can't figure out how to set up `grub`, which isn't showing up by default on system startup.

I've tried using `grub-install /dev/sda` (with and without `--recheck`), but all I get is:

```
Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.
sed: can't read /boot/grub/device.map: No such file or directory
grep: /boot/grub/device.map: No such file or directory
/dev/sda1 does not have any corresponding BIOS drive.
```

How can I properly set up `grub` on my machine? I'm specifically looking for the selection menu and option to go to a `grub` prompt on startup.

Answer (score 1):

Grub Customizer may be the answer:it let's you to show the menu, and configure the number of seconds until launching your default option:

[image: General settings - grub customizer]

Install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always had to use refind boot manager for Macs. You can install from a live boot disk/usb

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#linux

Comment: I've followed the instructions in your link, and my laptop now doesn't boot.

Comment: Did you use the manual setup or the ppa?  What happens when you try to boot?  If it were working correctly it would detect your OSs and give you a Grey screen with icons for each OS.  Does it get that far? Also what happens when you hold alt at boot?  Does it find a boot able drive? My guess is refind overwrote your grub on the efi drive but isn't detecting elementary for some reason.  Rebuilding grub can fix this.

Comment: I used the PPA install, but made sure (and updated) files so that they matched those mentioned in the manual install guide. I get a black screen which appears to persist indefinitely, and no OS selection screen at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "made sure (and updated) files so that they matched those mentioned in the manual install guide"

Comment: I'd made sure that the files the author mentions should be placed in specific points in the FS were actually in those places to _avoid_ the "unbootable" scenario he describes in one of the grey boxes on that webpage.

Comment: Okay, It is hard to install refind from a live usb boot, but isn't too hard to rebuild grub. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223856&page=3 has instructions that I've used from a loki boot disk before you may need to run the command sudo apt-get install software-properties-common to be able to add repos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47970/discussion-between-michael-roberts-and-jules).